# How to restore original android OS and remove cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

My situation is that I downloaded cyanogenmod and liked it. I then performed a factory reset and wipe data off of my phone. When a restart my phone, I no longer have google play store installed or any of the stock google apps for that matter.

What has gone wrong and how do I restore everything back to the stock version of android?(the way it was when I didn't have cyanogenmod and just the plain old android OS)

My phone was a Sony Xperia Z. It is running on android 5.1.1.

Comment: What is your device model? Flash a stock firmware

Comment: If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Apparently, you have not bothered to "merge" the accounts, despite being requested, that's the reason your proposed edit (assuming you opened two accounts to sign in) is rejected. Besides, you cannot have a question based on the answer edited into your original question.  If you want to ask , it *has* to be a separate question after verifying that it had not been asked earlier and answered

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to head back, why not flash GAPPS (Google Apps suite) if there's nothing wrong with CM itself? Get appropriate GAPPS for your Android version at [opengapps.org](http://opengapps.org).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed by @Andy Yan, you can download an appropriate GApps suite and flash it from the link that he has provided. If you still want to revert to stock, grab a stock firmware file from here https://xperiastockrom.com/sony-xperia-z-c6603 or from XDA and flash it using a flash tool.